# Instances of Dockerized spring-boot services keep failing in swarm mode. How to find the problem?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a test env where I have 2 machines, 1 manager and 1 worker in swarm mode. I deploy a stack of 10 services on the worker machine with 1 container for each service. The services start and after some time some instances die, then the manager again puts them in pending and so on keeps happening. The spring-boot services have no problem(I checked the log). To me it seems that the worker is not able to handle the 10 instances however I am not sure.

Are their any docker commands to find out whats going on here? Like some command which might say that the container was killed because it was out memory or something?

Comment: If you log into one of the hosts involved and run `dmesg`, is there a long ugly complaint from the kernel OOM killer?

Comment: Try to use "docker service logs SERVICE|TASK" command. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_logs/